# perl replace characters in a string but retain special character or space

Tags: perl, replace

I would like to create a program that replaces characters and retains the special characters. An example input and output is shown below.

Here's what I did so far:

```
$sentence = userinput;

@words = split(/ /, $sentence);

for ($i = 0; $i < @words.length; $i ++){
    $words[$i] =~ s/\W//g;
    @characters = split(//, $words[$i]);
    #print $words[$i] . "\n";

    $wordlength = length($words[$i]);


    for ($j = 0; $j < @characters.length; $j ++){

    $char = $characters[$j];

    for ($x = 0; $x < $wordlength; $x++){
        $char++;
        if ($char eq "aa"){
            $char = "a";
        }
        elsif ($char eq "AA"){
            $char = "A";
        }
    }
    print $char;
    if ($x = 0){
        $output[$i] = $char;
    }
    else {
        $output[$i] = join ($char);
    }
}

print $output[$i];
}
```

Input:

> Hi! how are you doing?

Output:

> Jk! krz duh brx itnsl?

Comment: And what in specific is preventing you from creating said program?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: sorry i dont get what you meant

Comment: They meant you didn't specify what you have tried, haven't shown any code, your expected output doesn't follow a strict and recognizable pattern, haven't specified the rules you wish to apply in replacing the characters, and haven't asked a question.

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far, but you might want to look at Perl's `tr` operator to get started. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html

Comment: yup but doesnt work as it takes in the whole word including the special character, if i remove the special character i dont know how to print it back 
Thanks for your help as im really new to perl

Comment: Are the replacement characters random or are there rules?

Comment: "`Ab! abc def ghi jklmn?`": Why "Ab" and then "abc"? What dictates when one should start over at "a" again?

Comment: there's rule. the first letter would be starting from abc base on the word count... retaining the special character, space and capital is also kept

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the problem with the program you present? Where did you get stuck? If you are looking for a code review, you could also try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `@words.length`? This is not Perl.

Comment: The rule doesn't match your sample output.  Why is it `Jk! klm...`? Why does `k` repeat?

Comment: @HåkonHægland that would get closed on CR, either as "unclear what you're asking" or more likely just as "broken code", since it doesn't appear that the code is working as intended. Please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/23788).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things in your code don't make sense:

- Missing `use strict; use warnings;`.
- All variables are global (you should be using `my` to create variables)
- `@foo.length` is not the number of elements in the array `@foo`. It's the number of elements in the array `@foo` concatenated with the number of characters in `$_` (because arrays in scalar context return their length, `.` concatenates strings, and `length` works on `$_` by default).
- `join ($char)` always returns the empty string: You're joining an empty list (no elements) using `$char` as a separator.

Here's an attempt to fix all of these issues:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sentence = readline;

$sentence =~ s{([A-Za-z]+)}{
    my $word = $1;
    join '', map {
        my $base = ord(/^[A-Z]/ ? 'A' : 'a');
        chr((ord($_) - $base + length($word)) % 26 + $base)
    } split //, $word
}eg;

print $sentence;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm really grateful towards you. I don't know it's such a short code to get my intended output.
Thanks once again melpomene

Comment: i would like to ask, what is the purpose of adding the eg; at the end of }?
Thank you!

Comment: @help See [`perldoc perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#s-PATTERN-REPLACEMENT-msixpodualngcer). Basically it tells Perl (`g`) to replace all occurrences of the pattern (without `g` it only does the first one) and (`e`) that the replacement part is a block of Perl code, not a plain string.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination:) its very detail 
Thanks once again
Thumbs up melpomene

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you are doing is rot3 encoding, but if so then your example is wrong

```
my $sentence = 'Hi! how are you doing?';
$sentence =~ tr/A-Za-z/D-ZA-Cd-za-c/;
print $sentence, "\n";
```

#### output

```
Kl! krz duh brx grlqj?
```

which is similar, but not identical to

```
Jk! krz duh brx itnsl?
```

Comment: No, each character is shifted by the length of the word it appears in.

Comment: @melpomene: I see. Not the best example is it, with three three-letter words! But then we're back to the question of what a word might be. In particular, your solution considers hyphenated words as two separate words, but the OP's code just deletes the hyphen